# SQL Server trigger : duplicate entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExampleForTrig 
(
     var1 int NOT NULL, 
     var2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     var3 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     var4 decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.amended 
(
    var1 int NOT NULL, 
    var2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    var3 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    var4 decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
    vara int NOT NULL, 
    varb varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    varc varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    vard decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
);
```

With some random information in the former.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ExampleForTrig (var1, var2, var3, var4) 
VALUES ('9', 'Geoff', 'D', '11.23');
INSERT INTO dbo.ExampleForTrig (var1, var2, var3, var4) 
VALUES ('9', 'Bill', 'E', '11.23');
INSERT INTO dbo.ExampleForTrig (var1, var2, var3, var4) 
VALUES ('9', 'John', 'H', '11.23');
```

The first table has an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger which enters the amended information alongside the new information into the `dbo.amended` table.

However, within the trigger, there is an issue with duplicate entries.

Sometimes, for one update, the trigger will populate `dbo.amended` with two of the same entry. I require assistance in identifying the error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.my_trig 
ON dbo.ExampleForTrig
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.amended (var1, var2, var3, var4, vara, varb, varc, vard)
        SELECT 
            del.var1, del.var2, del.var3, del.var4, 
            ins.var1, ins.var2, ins.var3, ins.var4
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                 var1, var2, var3, var4
             FROM 
                 deleted ) AS del, 
            (SELECT 
                 var1, var2, var3, var4
             FROM 
                 inserted) AS ins;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just selecting from both the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables - with **no** JOIN condition between the two!

That's bad practice anyway and has been deprecated from the SQL standard since **1992** - more than 20 years ago. Stop using this - use **proper ANSI/ISO JOIN** syntax (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) with a join condition instead.

You need to define what they are joined on - typically the **primary key** of the table (which I don't see what really is the PK in your case).

```
INSERT INTO dbo.amended (var1, var2, var3, var4, vara, varb, varc, vard)
    SELECT 
        del.var1, del.var2, del.var3, del.var4, 
        ins.var1, ins.var2, ins.var3, ins.var4
    FROM
        inserted AS ins
    INNER JOIN
        deleted AS del ON ins.PrimaryKey = del.PrimaryKey;
```

Otherwise, you're creating a **cartesian product** of each row from the `Inserted` table combined with each row from the `Deleted` table. If you updated 3 rows, you'll get **9 rows** inserted!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.